# Chain rule and derivative with matrix product?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, hadamard-product

I'm trying to compute some derivatives with given vectors and functions: column vector $X=[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n ]^T$ and $Z=[z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n ]^T$, row vector $Y=[y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n ]$

1. $f(X,Y)=e^{XY}$
   $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Y} = e^{XY}X $$
2. $f^T(X,Y)=(e^{XY})^T$
   $$\dfrac{\partial (e^{XY})^T}{\partial Y} =  $$
3. $f=XZ^T \odot e^{XY}$
   Using $\partial (A \odot B) = (\partial A) \odot B  + A \odot
       (\partial B)$

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} = \dfrac{\partial (XZ^T)}{\partial X} \odot e^{XY} + XZ^T \odot \dfrac{\partial  e^{XY}}{\partial X}$$
but it seems to me it is wrong cause $\partial (XZ^T)/\partial X$ will result in $Z$ which is vector and $e^{XY}$ is a matrix.

**Additional questions**

So, a stumbling block here is that we take derivative from a matrix by a vector which results in a tensor...

1. I haven't seen before the following expression. Taylor series?
   $$f(H) = f_0I + \dfrac{f_\lambda - f_0}{\lambda} H$$
   $$df(H) = \dfrac{f_\lambda - f_0}{\lambda} dH + \left( \dfrac{f_\lambda' }{\lambda} - \dfrac{f_\lambda - f_0 }{\lambda^2} \right)H d\lambda$$
   Does this apply to any analytical function and any matrix H?
2. I tried to rewrite few expressions and wondering whether the output for this operations would be different. I mean any chance to avoid 3-rank tensors and Khatri-Rao product
   $$\text{vec}(f_1) = \text{vec}(x_0^T\,\left( A \odot B \right)) = (I \otimes x_0^T)\, \text{vec}(A) \odot \text{vec}(B) \quad ?$$
   $$f_2 = G_1^T(x_0y_1^T)\,G_1(x_0y_1^T)\,y_2$$
   where $x_0,y_1,y_2$ are vectors and, for example, $G_1(x) = e^x$, $G_2(x)=1-e^{-x}$.
   Here we take derivatives from a vector by vector. In your answer you've used trick with diagonal matrices for rewriting Hadamard product, however in $f_1$ slightly another situation
   $$\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_1^T} = $$
3. 

$$\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y_2} = $$
4. I'm not sure what to do with $G_1^T$
$$\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_1^T} = $$
5.
$$\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y_2} = G_1^T(x_0y_1^T)\, G_1(x_0y_1^T)$$

**Update 2**

Having column vectors $x, y$ with dimensions *k*, *m* and rectangular matrix $H = xy^T$ with size k$\times$m let's compute derivative of function $f(H)$ with respect to vector $y^T$, where $f$ any analytical function ($e^x$ or $sin(x)$)
$$df = f'(H) \odot dH = f'(H) \odot (xdy^T)$$
\begin{align} 
\text{vec}(df) =& \, \text{vec}(f'(H)) \odot \text{vec}(xdy^T) \\
=& \,\text{diagvec}(f'(H))\, \text{vec}(xdy^T) \\
=& \,\text{diagvec}(f'(H))\, (I_m \otimes x) \, \text{vec}(dy^T)
\end{align}
$$\dfrac{\text{vec}(df)}{dy^T} = \,\text{diagvec}(f'(H))\, (I_m \otimes x)$$
Final vectorized derivative has size  (km$\times$m).

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\bx{\boxtimes}
\def\a{\phi}\def\b{\psi}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\l{\lambda}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\L(#1\R)}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\L(#1\R)}}
$First, for consistency let's use uppercase letters for matrices, lowercase for column vectors, and Greek letters for scalars. This renames your variables $(f,X,Y,Z)\to(F,x,y^T,z)$

For the first problem, notice that $H=xy^T$ is a rank-one matrix $$\eqalign{
H &= xy^T &\qiq dH = x\,dy^T\\
\l &= \trace H=x^Ty &\qiq d\l = x^Tdy \\
H^2 &= \l H &\qiq \c{H^k = \l^{k-1}H} \\
}$$
The last relationship means that any polynomial, power series,
or analytic function $f(z)$ can be reduced to a *linear function*
of $H,\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
f(H) &= f_0\,I + \LR{\frac{f_\l-f_0}{\l}}H \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad \\
&{\rm where}\quad f_\l=f(\l),\quad f_0=f(0) \\
}$$
and $I$ is the $(n\times n)$ identity matrix.

So for the exponential function we can calculate the differential as
$$\eqalign{
F_1 &= \exp(H) \\ &= I + \LR{\frac{e^\l-\o}{\l}}H \\
dF_1 &= \CLR{\frac{e^\l-\o}{\l}}dH
  \;+\; H\GLR{\frac{e^\l}{\l}-\frac{e^\l-\o}{\l^2}} d\l \\
 &= \c{\a}\,x\,dy^T \;+\; \g{\b}\,Hx^Tdy \\
}$$
Unfortunately, the gradient of a matrix with respect to a vector is a third-order **tensor**.

To avoid introducing tensor notation, let's use Kronecker products $(\otimes)$ to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrices in that last equation
$$\eqalign{
f_1 &= \vecc{F_1},\qquad h=\vecc H = y\otimes x \\
df_1 &= \BR{\a I\otimes x}\,dy + \b hx^T\,dy \\
\grad{f_1}{y}
 &= \BR{\a I\otimes x} + \b hx^T \\
 &= \LR{\frac{e^\l-\o}{\l}}\BR{I\otimes x} 
  + \LR{\frac{\l e^\l-e^\l+\o}{\l^2}}hx^T \\
}$$
In a similar way, you can calculate the gradient
with respect to  $x$.
$$\eqalign{
dF_1 &= \phi\,dx\,y^T + \psi Hy^Tdx \\
df_1 &= \BR{\a y\otimes I}\,dx + \b hy^T\,dx \\
\grad{f_1}{x} &= \LR{\a y\otimes I} + \b hy^T \\
}$$

I'm not sure about the intent of the second function.

The third function, can be rewritten using diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Diag{x} \qif x = \diag{X} \\
Z &= \Diag{z} \qif z = \diag{Z} \\
F_3 &= xz^T \odot F_1 \;=\; XF_1Z \\
dF_3 &= dX\,F_1Z + X\,dF_1\,Z \\
}$$
and the Khatri-Rao product $(\bx)$
$$\eqalign{
\vecc{AXB} &= \LR{B^T\bx A}x \\
{B^T\bx A}
 &= \BR{B^T\otimes\o_a}\odot\BR{\o_b\otimes A} \\
}$$
yielding
$$\eqalign{
\vecc{dF_3} &=  \LR{ZF_1^T\bx I}dx + \LR{Z\otimes X}df_1 \\
df_3
 &= \LR{ZF_1^T\bx I}dx
  + \LR{Z\otimes X}\LR{\a y\otimes I}\,dx
  + \LR{Z\otimes X}\LR{\b hy^T}\,dx
\\
\grad{f_3}{x}
 &= \LR{ZF_1^T\bx I}
  + \a\LR{Z\otimes X}\LR{y\otimes I} 
  + \b\LR{Z\otimes X}\LR{hy^T} 
\\\\
}$$

---

NB: If $x$ and $y$ are (nearly) orthogonal, then
$\,(\l,\phi,\psi)\to\LR{0,\o,\tfrac{\o}{2}}$

### Update

Rename $(x_0,y_1,y_2)\to(x,y,z)$, then in response to your additional questions...

1. The given expression is derived from the Taylor series using the fact that $H^2 = \l H$ which allows all higher powers of the matrix to be reduced to $H^{p+1}=\l^pH\;-$ but this special reduction formula *only* holds for rank-one matrices.
2. The term $\LR{G_2}$ is a matrix, while $\LR{x^TG_1 zz^T}$ is a row vector, so their Hadamard product is not defined.
3. Since $f_1$ is not defined, neither is its gradient.
4. Note that $G_2=\LR{I-G_1^{-1}}\,$ and $\,G_1$ is just a repeat of your original function $F_1=\exp(H)=G_1$ and you already know its differential
   $$\eqalign{
   dG_1 &= \a x\,dy^T + \b Hx^Tdy \\
   dG_2 &= G_1^{-1}\,dG_1\,G_1^{-1} \\
   }$$
   Now you wish to incorporate $G_1$ into a vector function
   $$\eqalign{
   f_2 &= G_1^TG_1z \\
    &= F_1^TF_1z \\
   df_2 &= dF_1^TF_1z + F_1^TdF_1z \\
    &= \LR{z^TF_1^T\otimes I}\vecc{dF_1^T}
     + \LR{z^T\otimes F_1^T}\vecc{dF_1} \\
    &= \BR{\LR{z^TF_1^T\otimes I}K + \LR{z^T\otimes F_1^T}}\;df_1 \\
   }$$
   where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#2) associated with the `vec()` operation, and the differential $df_1$ was previously derived.
5. Correct

Comment: I've added some additional questions to my post. Thank you very much for the answers and help. I think you should create some kind of scientific math channel on utube or write your own book (in case if you don't have it)! @greg your material is so great.

Comment: I do appoligize for $f_1$ function. I think, I should make corrections to $f_1$

Comment: Should it be $(z^T \otimes F_1^T)\text{vec}(dF_1)$ in $df_2$ 2nd term?

Comment: From $df_1$: $\text{vec}(\phi x \, dy^T) = \phi(I \otimes x) \text{vec} (dy^T)$ and $\text{vec} (dy^T) = \text{vec} (dy)$ right? cause it's vector, not a matrix

Comment: Yes, to both comments.

Comment: I made changes to $f_1$, so now it's possible to compute the gradient (see Update section)
$$f_1 = x_0^T\,\left( G_1(x_0y_1^T)\,y_2 y_2^T \odot G_2(x_0y_1^T) \right) = x_0^T\,\left( A \odot B \right)$$
$$\text{vec}(f_1) = \text{vec}(x_0^T\,\left( A \odot B \right)) = (I \otimes x_0^T)\, \text{vec}(A) \odot \text{vec}(B) = (I \otimes x_0^T)\, \text{Diag}\left[ \text{vec}(A)\right] \, \text{vec}(B)$$
@greg not sure if it's right way

Comment: You're headed in the right direction. Now calculate the differential
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(df_1)
&= (I\otimes x_0^T)\;{\rm Diagvec}(A)\;{\rm vec}(dB) 
 + (I\otimes x_0^T)\;{\rm Diagvec}(B)\;{\rm vec}(dA) \\
df_1&= \;M_a\,db \;+\; M_b\,da \\
}$$

Comment: Just before doing this, could you please clarify the following:
1. Does this property 
$$\text{vec} (ab^T) = (b \otimes a)$$
hold for any $a,b$ vectors?
2. 
$$\text{vec} (\psi x y^T x^T dy ) =  \psi (y \otimes x) x^T dy \quad ?$$

Comment: probably because we asssume that $\text{vec}(x^T dy) = x^T dy$, it's just a number

Comment: What will happen if $x$ and $y^T$ have different dimensions? Matrix $H=xy^T$ is no longer square and we can't use $f(H) = f_0 I + ...$ @greg

Comment: Looks like you're figuring things out. If $H$ is rectangular, then one typically resorts to elementwise functions, i.e. $\,F_{ij}=f\left(H_{ij}\right),\;$ in which case the differential is given by $$dF=f'(H)\odot dH$$ Such elementwise analysis is usually simpler than the matrixwise analysis $-$ except you must deal with lots of Hadamard products!$\;$

Comment: I've tried to use your suggestions, @greg, and added Update 2 to my post. Does this have any sense in case of rectangular matrix? Also, got stuck with matching dimensions in the final output. Thanks!